# Problem building Django + PostgreSQL containers in Docker on Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, docker

I created dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code/
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

and docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
  web:
    build: D:/djangoProject/phonerep/Docker/
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
       - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
networks:
      djangonetwork:
          driver: bridge
```

But there is an error when starting the web container in docker console:

> web_1 | connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
> web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 127, in connect
> web_1 | conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
> web_1 | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

And when you start the container with PostgreSQL:

> db_1 | 2021-04-22 08:51:15.580 UTC [85] FATAL: data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has invalid permissions
> db_1 | 2021-04-22 08:51:15.580 UTC [85] DETAIL: Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).
> db_1 | child process exited with exit code 1
> db_1 | initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
> db_1 | running bootstrap script ... phonerep_db_1 exited with code 1

content of settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run it all on Widnows 10, unfortunately so far I can't change the development platform to a Linux-like system.
Please tell me how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I show that your setting is hard coded :
I think you should make it configurable using the variable putted inside your docker-compose file
like that:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ['POSTGRES_DB'],
        'USER': os.environ['POSTGRES_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['POSTGRES_DB_SERVICE'],
        'PORT': os.environ['POSTGRES_PORT']
    }
}
```

and add to your docker-compose be like:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
  web:
    build: D:/djangoProject/phonerep/Docker/
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432 # add database port
      - POSTGRES_DB_SERVICE=db # add database host
    volumes:
       - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
networks:
      djangonetwork:
          driver: bridge
```

But before that be sure that you can access to your database using

```sh
$ docker exec -it postgres_container /bin/sh
$ psql 
--- will ask you for password
```

you can follow this link to show how you can use [psql](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/postgresql/connect-to-postgresql-from-the-command-line)
I think that can help you to resolve your issue

Comment: The problem is that the postgres container just doesn't start, only the django container starts. From here, it will not work to enter the container with postgres. Unfortunately, your code did not help me

Answer (score 0):

If Postgres doesn't working you need to follow this steps:

1. configure docker-compose to use the postgresql container
2. log in to the postgresql container
3. Try to create a table

If this all steps is ok you can just add the django part at the end .

#### Create Postgresql container using Docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: "postgres" # use latest official postgres version
    env_file:
      - database.env # configure postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts downvolumes:
  database-data: # named volumes can be managed easier using docker-compose
```

The database.env file looks like this:

```sh
# database.env
POSTGRES_USER=unicorn_user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=magical_password
POSTGRES_DB=rainbow_database
```

#### Log In to PostgreSQL

```sh
docker-compose up
```

#### Connect to database:

```sh
docker-compose run database bash
database# psql --host=database --username=unicorn_user --dbname=rainbow_database
```

I tried it for you and all working correctly as you can see :
[image]

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue .